# Printing on transparency sheets with a Dell 5130cdn printer

Tags: printing, printer, transparency

I am trying to determine if I will melt transparency sheets and destroy my boss' Dell 5130cdn printer if I attempt to print them. We have 3M LaserJet and HP InkJet transparency sheets available and the printer manual says it can print transparencies but I don't know if I need to have specific brands or if what we have will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I don't know if I need to have specific brands or if what we have will work.

You cannot use the Inkjet sheets.

Check the specification of your laser compatible transparency sheets:

- Must be able to withstand temperatures of 205°C (401°F)
- Must not be Non-white transparencies

Complete instructions are as follows:

> - When printing on transparencies:
> - Set the paper type to Transparency  from the printer driver to avoid damaging your printer.
> - Use transparencies designed specifically for laser printers. Do not use regular transparencies.
> - Transparencies must be able to withstand temperatures of 205°C (401°F) without melting, discoloring, offsetting or releasing
>     hazardous emissions.
> - Avoid getting fingerprints on the transparencies. This may result in poor print quality.
> - Before loading transparencies, fan the stack to prevent sheets from sticking together.
> - Non-white transparencies are not supported with the printer.

Source [Dell™ 5130cdn Color Laser Printer User's Guide](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_printers_main/esuprt_printers/dell-5130cdn_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf)

Comment: how do I find those specifications? It does not appear to be on the packaging or the website. I called 3M but had to leave a message.

Comment: @Ken No idea :/

Comment: If the transparencies are rated as "suitable for copiers" or "suitable for laser printers", then they will work in a laser printer. Those rated as "for inkjets" should not be used. "3M Laserjet" transparencies should be fine, as Laserjets are laser printers.